# Getting Black screen between Activities-Android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

I am not doing any network operation like downloading images or media in my Ui thread. i have a very complex UI that takes around 8 seconds to load and black screen comes in between , is there any way i can optimize it or show some kind of progress bar while my second activity loads its UI and remove the progress when i am done.

I cannot use asynctask doInBackground() since everything is UI only --Like For loops for creating LinearLayout childs dynamically, Putting views side by side on relativelayout and reordering them as per business rule. changing various image colors as per business rule etc.

Is there any way i can optimize this and reduce loading time?

Comment: It might be helpful to post some code, so the developers can help you.

Comment: Depending on your requirement you can try to use some other layouts instead of only using LinearLayouts. If you could post your layout we might be able to help you more

Answer (score 0):

Why you need such a complex layout in the first place? if the layout is too complex then it should NOT be. Try to find a simpler layout, if you must follow the current layout then I suggest an idea but it is not recommended.

Here is the idea, it's based on iOS development, you should take a snapshot of the complete layout (without any actual content, just layout) and display on top of your layout when you first load your activity. After all of your underneath layout already loaded, then you remove the snapshot on top and make the real layout visible (all the process must show the loading progress to avoid user interact with your UI). Although this is not ideal, it should help in your case.